# How do you describe a sound that is mellifluous and sounds like when crystals crash?

Tags: adjectives

I don't know if i've describe it clearly or not, the bell-sounding, chipper sound, also the sound that wind chimes make, I always say *the crystal-like sound* which I'm not really content with, I really want to find a word which can describe this sound that makes me so happy and chill, can you guys help me with the adjective?

Comment: Check out synonyms for [***chiming, tinkling***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/chime). Some are positive, some negative, and some "neutral".